# $E$-orientation of a closed manifold induce $E$-orientation of normal bundle: passage in the proof.

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

I'm trying to follow [Kochman's proof](https://books.google.de/books?id=Q0LiOrRmm7oC&lpg=PA131&vq=oriented%20spectrum&hl=it&pg=PA132#v=snippet&q=proposition%204.3.5&f=false) of the well-known result

> For a ring spectrum $E$, and closed manifold $M^n$ together with an embedding in $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$, the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. the vector bundle is $E$-oriented
> 2. $M^n$ is $E$-oriented.

In the proof of $1\Rightarrow 2$, he makes use of this commutative diagram

[image]

My question is the following: **why the capping with $U$ and $U'$ on the left and right column respectively induce an isomorphism?**

They much resemble Thom isomorphisms. The problem is that Thom isomorphisms are proved in the following page. I'm wondering if there is a way to show that it is an iso **without** the full power of Thom Isomorphism theorem, or if it is just a "wrong placing" of this proposition, which should go after Thom Isos theorem.